# Best way to store authentication token on SPA

Tags: cookies, http-headers, single-page-application

I have Web API server and client in browser. Now i want to realize authentication system. Is it good way to store authentication tokens in cookies on client and make every HTTP request with 'Athorization' header(set this header from cookies)?